# Why does the getAnnotation method of Method needs class as parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

I am reading about annotations and can't understand why `getAnnotation` of `Method` needs class as parameter. Consider the following code:

```
Class<?> c = ob.getClass();//From here we get the Class object
Method m = c.getMethod("myMeth");//we get Method object (we know from what Class)
MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);//and here we pass Class. Why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a method can have multiple annotations of possibly multiple types.

[`getAnnotation(annotationClass)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) takes as parameter the class of the wanted annotation to retrieve:

> Returns this element's annotation for the specified type if such an annotation is present, else null.

If you don't give a wanted class, you can't know which annotation to return. Consider

```
@MyAnnotation1(value = "a") @MyAnnotation2(value = "b")
public void foo() { }
```

If you want the `value` of the annotation `MyAnnotation1`, you need somehow to tell which annotation you want to retrieve for the method `foo`: there are 2. This is done by giving the class of the annotation.

On the other hand, if you want to retrieve *all* annotations on a method, you can call [`getDeclaredAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations--) (to have the annotation directly present on the method) or [`getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getAnnotations--) (to have direct and inherited annotations).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get all the method annotations you should use:

```
Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

And `getAnnotation` method from your sample returns annotation of the fiven type if it is declared on the method